# Can't resolve 'react-dom' in /ButtonBase'

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, node-modules, npm-install, npm-start

I'm trying to run a `React` project created in Mac, I had not this problem neither in Windows or Mac, but I'm facing the following errors when I try to run (`npm start`) in Ubuntu:

`./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js`

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in '/node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/ButtonBase'`

I tried to delete `node_modules` and ran `npm install` again, but the problem persists.

Can someone  help me with this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this

Comment: I really don't remeber quite well, but I think the issue was solved after installing another version of node in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Just install react and react-dom

```
npm i react react-dom
```